# How to run INSTALL with Visual Studio's CMake support?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017

With [CMake support in Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/), how can I run the INSTALL build?

[image]
From the CMake menu in the top toolbar, I don't see any selection to run the INSTALL project.

EDIT: The minimum settings suggested by [vre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5251059/vre) worked, the INSTALL option showed up in the toolbar menu:

- CMakeLists.txt

  ```
  # 3.9.2 is the current version the newest VS is using
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.2)
  project(test2017)
  add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
  install(TARGETS hello DESTINATION hello/bin)
  ```
- hello.cpp

But when I moved `hello.cpp` to a subfolder, the option was gone:

- CMakeLists.txt

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.2)
  project(test2017)
  add_subdirectory("src")
  ```
- src/CMakeLists.txt

  ```
  add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
  install(TARGETS hello DESTINATION "hello/bin")
  ```
- src/hello.cpp

Comment: Can you add the contents of the CMakeSettings.json and CMakeLists.txt? I tried with VS2017 15.5.5 with the following CMakeLists.txt `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

project(test2017)

add_executable(hello hello.cpp)

install(TARGETS hello DESTINATION hello/bin)` and the install option was shown both in the Toolbar menu and in the context menu of CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Maybe this bug (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/46744/vs2017-152-cmake-missing-install-menu-option.html) in VS2017 15.2 is affecting you?

Comment: @vre I added an CMakeLists example as you suggested. When I moved the cpp files to another folder, the install option disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169923/cmake-missing-install-menu-option-when-using-subfo.html) when using subfolders and still hasn't been fixed in the current VS 15.5.5.

A workaround is adding an `install` argument to `buildCommandArgs` inside the `CMakeSettings.json` file. Example:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x86-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x86" ],
      "buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "-v install",
      "ctestCommandArgs": ""
    }
  ]
}
```